# xv6: what does `popl 0(%eax)` mean? (OSTEP)

Tags: xv6

In Operating Systems, Three Easy Pieces Chapter 6, there is a code snippet from xv6's context switch:

```
...
void swtch(struct context **old, struct context *new);
#
# Save current register context in old
# and then load register context from new.
.globl swtch
swtch:
# Save old registers
movl 4(%esp), %eax # put old ptr into eax
popl 0(%eax) # save the old IP
movl %esp, 4(%eax) # and stack
movl %ebx, 8(%eax) # and other registers
...
```

I understand that `movl 4(%esp), %eax` moves the content inside the address `4(%esp)` (first parameter of the method, or the old context address) to register `eax`.

However, the next line `popl 0(%eax)` seems to also pop from the stack (which points to the instruction pointer of the caller) and load it into `eax`. However, my understanding is contradicting because that would mean we're loading two values into `eax`.

Which part am I not following correctly here?

I assume that `0(%eax)` is not loading into `eax` but perhaps loading into the address pointed by `eax`? That would make sense since `eax` pointing at the old context address.

Comment: I would have say that `popl 0(%eax)` does not pop to `eax`, but to `eax[0]`